# Showing button below a fragment in an activity

Tags: android, layout

I'm quite new to Android. I have a very simple layout that doesn't work yet:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
    <fragment android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="pl.nscr.playwatch.MainActivity$WatchListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/watchlist"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Start service"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my problem is that the fragment spans the whole available height in an activity. I'd like to be able to see that button below it, but I don't actually know how to layout this thing.

I tried using RelativeLayout, but I ended up with the button showing above the fragment which looks ugly. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Apparently it was a silly mistake. I changed back again to RelativeLayout but the layout now has width and height set to 'fill_parent' and everything works as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
    <fragment android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="pl.nscr.playwatch.MainActivity$WatchListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/watchlist"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnStartService"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@id/btnStartService"
            android:text="Start service"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

do the following

1. add android:orientation="vertical" attribute to `<LinearLayout>`
2. add layout_weight="1" attribute to `<fragment />`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the LinearLayout..